# how to write COUNT(DISTINCT()) query?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, sqlite

Please help me with this query.

I have a table student which looks like:

```
*id, name, surname, year, course*
1, John, Johnson, 3, Economy
2, Lara, Croft, 2, Biology
3, Mark, Jones, 3, Economy
4, Jim, Smith, 1, IT
5, Sarah, Kennedy, 1, IT
6, Matt, Damon, 3, Economy
```

And would like to get as a Result Set all courses with number of students attending, like:

```
*course, count*
Economy, 3
IT, 2
Biology, 1
```

Comment: What's your own best shot? What does it return? What do you think is wrong with it? We'll step in to help then.

Comment: You seem to know what function to use; try putting it in a query.

Comment: Your sample data doesn't show any need for `DISTINCT`.

Comment: Uh my try is very wrong. SELECT course, COUNT(DISTINCT(id)) FROM student;   I get Economy, 6 as a result.

Comment: @Prpaa: As you are using `count` that will cause an implicit group for the entire result. Selecting any data without an aggregate will get one of the values in the group even if there are different values, so the implicit grouping is only useful if you only get data by aggregates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't use `count(distinct ...)` for this, just group on the course and use `count()`:

```
select
  cource,
  count(*)
from
  Students
group by
  cource
order by
  cource
```

---

Using `count(distinct ...)` is useful if you want to make a distinct count within a group, for example counting the different values for `year` (in the implicit group of all the records):

```
select
  count(distinct year)
from
  Students
```

This would give you the result `3` as there are the three distinct values `1`, `2` and `3`.